# Textfields not passing values properly

Tags: javascript, html

I'm willing to use two textfields to pass on values via url.
Here are my textfields:

```
<h3 class="title1">Email</h3>
<input type="text" id="myTextField1" />
<br/><br/>
<h3 class="title2">Secret</h3>
<input type="text" id="myTextField2" />
<br/><br/>
```

There's a link below them:

```
<a id="myLink" href="index2.php"></a>
```

Then there's a function I use, which should create something like:

```
index2.php?email=value1&secret=value2
```

However what I am getting is:

```
index2.php?email=value1, secret=value1&email=value2, secret=value2
```

This is the function I use:

```
document.querySelector('#myBtn').addEventListener('click', function change() {
  function isInvalid(input) {
    return input.value.length == 0;
  }


  var inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll('[id^="myTextField"]')];
  var anchor = document.getElementById('myLink');

  var querystring = inputs.map((input) => {
      // Remove all leading non-digits to get the number //ex bladiebla1 = 1
      var number = input.id.replace( /^\D+/g, '');

      var titles = [...document.querySelectorAll('.title'+ number)];
      titles.forEach((title) => title.innerHTML = input.value);
      return `email=${input.value}`+` secret=${input.value}`;
  });

  anchor.href = `index2.php?${querystring.join('&')}`;

  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = querystring;
});
```

I realize that it is wrong and I get why this doesn't return what I want however I do not know how to fix this..
Could anybody tweek my code and point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overcomplicating things here a bit.

You have the inputs in the `inputs` variable. If they had a `name` attribute in the html you can simply map over them and get the values out.

You don't really need the bit where you parse the number from the ID.

```js
document.querySelector('#myBtn').addEventListener('click', function change() {
  function isInvalid(input) {
    return input.value.length == 0;
  }


  var inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll('[id^="myTextField"]')];
  var anchor = document.getElementById('myLink');

  var querystring = inputs.map((input) => {
      return `${input.name}=${input.value}`;
  });

  anchor.href = `index2.php?${querystring.join('&')}`;

  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = querystring.join('&');
});
```

```html
<h3 class="title1">Email</h3>
<input type="text" name="email" id="myTextField1" />
<br/><br/>
<h3 class="title2">Secret</h3>
<input type="text" name="secret" id="myTextField2" />
<br/><br/>

<button id=myBtn>Run the function</button>

<a id=myLink>Target Link</a>


<h3>Results:</h3>
<div id=result></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You iterate through each input and set email and secret for each of two inputs. Just add check for id. Something like `return number === 1 ? email=${input.value} : &secret=${input.value};`

Comment: Is it possible for you to show what you mean using my code?